# Keeping track of unread comments in Mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I've got an Meteor/React app that has a chat window for all signed in users. Comments are stored in Mongo:

```
{ 
  "_id" : "vA6uLZA8AmYLf8NxA", 
  "comment" : "yada yada", 
  "name" : "JOHN DOE", 
  "date" : "Tue 9:07 pm", 
  "value" : NumberInt(20) // this number increments by one for each comment
}
```

I'm going to use a badge to set the count of unread messages. All unread messages will be considered "read" (unread count set to 0) if the chat page is mounted.

I'm struggling to implement this effectively. I'm thinking that localStorage would have to keep track of the "last seen" message count somehow and some sort of comparison made between the localStorage value and the current message count in Mongo?

How would you go about it?

Comment: sorry but dint't quite understand the scenario. Looks like you will have each comment as separate document in a mongo collection. Then what is `"value"` field is about ? why are you incrementing it ?

Comment: Maybe you can create a new collection having all the user read messages. You can store this collection locally too (so that users can see previous messages even with no internet collection). Then you can compare the documents of these with the chat collection. eg : message A is posted by a user. It is inserted in Chat Collection. Then after user visits the specific chat (comments are rendered), userChatMessage is created for that document. You can use this structure easily to find the unread messages and implement other features too!

Comment: Good idea. Create another collection keeping track.